# Map over class methods

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a bunch of methods.

```js
class Users {
  member1(req: M1Request): Promise<M2Response>;
  member2(req: M2Request): Promise<M2Response>;
  member3(req: M3Request): Promise<M3Response>;
}

class OtherClassToWrap { ... }
```

I'm wrapping it's methods with a different signature, to add an extra arg:

```js
let rawUsers = ... as Users;
let wrappedUsers = wrap(users);

wrappedUsers.member1(... as M1Request, extraArg).then((res: M1Response) => { ... })
```

I need to properly type `wrap` function to define types for the resulting object members.

```js
const wrap = <T>(toWrap: T): ? => {
    let result = {} as T;
    for (const k in t) {
        result[k] = (req, extraArg) => toWrap[k](req);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I tried using `[P in keyof T]`, but I got too confused with how to apply it for this particular case.

Comment: The original functions always have just one parameter ? If not could you add the extra parameter at the start ? That would make this possible.

Comment: I can't change the source of the class I'm trying to wrap.

Comment: That was not the question, do the functions in the source always have one parameter ? Or do they have more parameters

Comment: Technically, the underlying function has two parameters. It supports two call signatures:

1) `(req: TReq, cb: Function) => void`
2) `(req: TReq) => Promise<TRes>`

Comment: I only need to support the second use-case, and can loose the type definition for the first one, so for the reasonable purposes we can consider the fns to only have a single argument.

Comment: I added solutions for either case in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your functions always have one parameter you can use conditional types to extract the parameter and add the extra parameter at the end:

```
type MapFunction<T, TExtra> = {
     [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (req: infer P) => infer R ? ((req: P, extra: TExtra) => R): T[P]
}
const wrap = <T extends Record<keyof T, (req: any) => Promise<any>>>(toWrap: T): MapFunction<T, string> => {
    let result = {} as MapFunction<T, string>;
    for (const k in toWrap) {
        result[k] = ((req: any, extraArg: any) => toWrap[k](req)) as any;
    }
    return result;
}


let rawUsers = null! as Users;
let wrappedUsers = wrap(rawUsers);
wrappedUsers.member1(null! as M1Request, "").then(o => {}) // o is M2Response
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-xpKdgGdzgB09Syrj7akHw+8bWAKwAROf-FvgAALb4uQRg7iggD0r6gT8ilF61QgQA)

If your functions have multiple parameters then we can't easily add the extra parameter at the end. We can add them at the start using tuples in spread parameters:

```
declare class Users {
  member1(req: M1Request): Promise<M2Response>;
  member2(req: M2Request): Promise<M2Response>;
  member3(req: M3Request, other: string): Promise<M3Response>;
}

type MapFunction<T, TExtra> = {
     [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: infer A) => infer R ? ((extra: TExtra, ...a: A) => R): T[P]
}
const wrap = <T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any) => any>>(toWrap: T): MapFunction<T, string> => {
    let result = {} as MapFunction<T, string>;
    for (const k in toWrap) {
        result[k] = ((req: any, extraArg: any) => toWrap[k](req)) as any;
    }
    return result;
}


let rawUsers = null! as Users;
let wrappedUsers = wrap(rawUsers);
wrappedUsers.member1("", null! as M1Request).then(o => {}) // o is M2Response
wrappedUsers.member3("", null! as M3Request, "").then(o => {}) // o is M3Response
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgjAJQgRwK4QM7CgXigbwF8AoUSWAJiTU2zyNPGhgGZr0tcCSzmrMwAewB2GaPR5NYbASLFcGAEwgBjADYBDAE7R1GjBigBVMVsP5iUKAFsI1gEYQtcABQ7kALliIUHYAEovAAUtQWsASzEAHhh+DCFRCAA+AG5LGztHLQo3FC9Y9lpAqBCwyIgYuISxVPTbBycWXM9pQqwAGihBYAALJy8sLXDhAHNi0ojo1iR4uWS0kkZyGA0wADFUYRVgcJEogBVO-YBRAA9gLQ0khXSrKABtIKhhqABrCBBBADMofYBdLz7R5-KAQc4QYSKQwuAB0cI0XmGXycUAAgv5cNckSiEFAAPxQFwuMEXBG-M6kzpwmFk9GYqAIYpAoJ-YgkFRybAAd0uYC4B1B4MhhiQHK0iii70+P0OhOpZI0whAGJw10VICSSRcwEEAHVeYDiit1pttrthAdOoNhiNrqqCLcoGoINgdBhUGo6NwoPpYKsNlsdntZdbRrU7lAvoItISOaJsK9nsIoDr9asMRYIxG3R7gPdXiC8ET3F51Z0SZdUVoRqWlSrrqnefm-s1-Bjfeq0hGSNmXagtMmc56FsRR87XRouSYnIY8MIPWoAIQ+wzTsxpcdQHmrSCKNezre8tyT-f+NLbsC7-cw+pZVwAInvnXnaiXK+8bQCMN6EJcgnpRAYgA9EBXTPIYBSyIkxAXlepgYDemSNC4j7Pguy6+tMvi0J0j7+N+fTCH+AGEMBoH-pErRQWIQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: I have an issue: `TypeError: wrappedUser.member1 is not a function`. How can I debug it? I get this error with my real code, and it occurs when I call `wrappedUser.member1({ ... })`.

Comment: Oddly, I only get it in jest. Seems like it's a different kind of issue. Thanks.

Comment: @user330199 I did not necessarily check the mapping code, only focused on the types.

Comment: Right, the problem was not with the types, but with the underlying JS. The error wording was confusing, but I figured it out.
Thanks again!